# How to replace word with javascript?

Tags: javascript, replace

In some forum I join, they just replace some link with something like spam or deleted. Example: www.rapidshare.com/download/123 will automatically turn to www.spam.com/download/123 OR word MONEY will change to BOSS.

Its really annoyed me because I have to rename back manually if I want to download. Is there any Javascript that can solve this that will replace back www.spam.com to www.rapidshare.com? I mean in client side.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### If these URLs are in `href` attributes...

```
var replaceHrefAttributes = function (element, search, replace) {
    var nodes = element.getElementsByTagName('a');

    for (var i = 0, length = nodes.length; i < length; i++) {

        var node = nodes[i];

        if (node.href == undefined) {
            continue;
        }

        node.href = node.href.replace(new RegExp(search, 'g'), replace);
    }

}
```

Your usage may be something like...

```
replaceHrefAttributes(document.body, 'www.spam.com', 'www.rapidshare.com');
```

---

#### If these URLs are inline text...

You could iterate over all text nodes, using `replace()` to replace any string with another.

Here is a general purpose recursive function I've written to do this...

```
var replaceText = function replaceText(element, search, replace) {
    var nodes = element.childNodes;

    for (var i = 0, length = nodes.length; i < length; i++) {

        var node = nodes[i];

        if (node.childNodes.length) {
            replaceText(node, search, replace);
            continue;
        }

        if (node.nodeType != 3) {
            continue;
        }

        node.data = node.data.replace(new RegExp(search, 'g'), replace);
    }

}
```

Your usage may be something like...

```
replaceText(document.body, 'www.spam.com', 'www.rapidshare.com');
```

If you are curious as to how the code works, here is a brief explanation...

1. Get all child nodes of the `element`. This will get text nodes and elements.
2. Iterate over all of them.
3. If this node has child nodes of its own, call the function again with `element` as the `element` in the loop. `continue` because we can't modify this as it is not a text node.
4. If this node's `nodeType` property is not `3` (i.e. a text node), then `continue` as again we can't modify any text.
5. We are confident this is a text node now, so replace the text.

You could make this function more flexible by passing `search` straight to it, allowing it to search for text using a string or a regular expression.

Comment: Looks good, except that I think OP wants to replace `hrefs` of links. ;o) (Pretty sure anyway.)

Comment: @patrickdw: I think you may be correct, cheers. I'll modify :)

Comment: Hmmm... Looking at this `if (node.href != undefined) { continue; }`, and I'm thinking you meant `== undefined`. But then I *am* getting sleepy...

Comment: The continue seems redundant, why not make the test `node.nodeType == 3` and do the processing in the block?

Comment: great answer! can this be used for greasemonkey userscript?

Comment: @RobG: I'm a fan of doing it this way.

Comment: @One: Sorry I don't. Do you have an error? Make sure you use the code above (I updated it an hour ago).

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0, len = a.length ; i < len ; i += 1) {
    a.firstChild.nodeValue = a.href;
}
```

Comment: You are assuming that all A elements have a *firstChild* and an *href* property. They may not. A better strategy would be to use the *document.links* collection.